# Show unused device driver

Tags: usb, drivers

When we plug in the USB game pad, it installs the device driver and starts to show up in the device manager. Can we somehow extract the driver from the device and install it such that it shows in device manager all the time irrespective of whether device is plugged in or not?

Comment: You don't have to "extract" the driver: it is installed. I change to title of your question from "extract" to "show unused"...

Answer (score 1):

*The driver is still there (installed) but "ghosted"...*

**1)** Add this environment variable: `devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices` with the value of **1**

[image: env var show hidden drvr]

**2)** Launch `devmgmt.msc` and choose the option to show hidden drivers

In this example, the driver for the *unplugged* digital camera appear in the list...

[image: devmgmt show hiddden]

Done.

Comment: Thanks a lot climenole. But there is one more thing i would like to know. Does showing ghosted drivers mean that system would behave exactly the same way as when device was connected. For example, if I have a application which works according to the number of usb devices connected. Will this application see the device as connected when its corresponding ghost driver is shown.

If not,then how is it possible to make my application believe that a usb device is connected when it is not?

Awaiting your reply. Thanks